# non-continuous numbering equation

Tags: equations, numbering

From the beginning of my document which contains two pages, I have several equations. Equation in page `2` must be started from `1` (numbered from `1`) How can I perform this procedure?

Comment: are you sure you want to number the equations in page 1? if so putting `\setcounter{equation}{0}` before the equation you want to reset should work

Comment: `\counterwithin*{page}{equation}`?

Comment: very good comments!!!

Comment: Note that paragraphs are formatted on one page, then split in two at the bottom of the page.  For this to work you may need to occasionally manually break pages.  `\def\nopar{{\parfilskip=0pt\par}\noindent}`